# Why does SQL server's Date format affect date conversions with Timestamps

Tags: sql-server, datetime, casting

I'm trying to convert a varchar containing a date into a datetime field in SQL server using the following script

```
SELECT cast('2017-12-14 14:30:41.007' as datetime)
```

When I ran this on my local Machine that uses DateFormat myd this worked fine and returned a valid datetime.
When I ran this statement on my server that uses Dateformat dym the server returned the following error

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

Why is '2017-12-14 14:30:41.007' a valid datetime under "myd" but not under "dym" even though it's neither a "dym" nor a "myd" date?

I have found a work around for the issue btw, I'm asking because i want to understand what is going on in SQL server

Comment: because you did not use a language neutral format. Use yyyymmdd hh:nn:ss

Comment: http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Comment: Because in some (in fact, most) languages that format is interpreted by SQL Server as `yyyy-dd-mm`. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5206/sql-server-datetime-best-practices/

Comment: You are dealing with strings, not dates or timestamps. *Don't* use strings, use the appropriate type.

Comment: @GuidoG that *is* an almost-neutral format. The full ISO8601 format is the same with a `T` between the date and time part.

Comment: It's a staging database which gets data bulk inserted from a CSV file. Using strings means that i can get all the data into tables and then mess about casting when i import it from the staging database to the actual database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes but almost is not full

Comment: @zeocrash then modify your batch import script to tread the field as a datetime with a specific format/culture. Or use `PARSE` passing a specific culture to *convert* that string to a valid datetime. The language format affects only the placement of the various parts in *some* formats. Different cultures have different separators though. Don't leave anything to chance

Comment: Thanks guys, you've been most informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because SQL server is interpreting 14 as a month number and there are only 12 months. If you change the 14 to 11 and run this script you will see the difference:

```
SET DATEFORMAT myd
SELECT DATEPART(month,cast('2017-12-11 14:30:41.007' as datetime))

SET DATEFORMAT dym
SELECT DATEPART(month,cast('2017-12-11 14:30:41.007' as datetime))

/*

Output:
12
11

*/
```

To make things consistent for all time formats put a T in the middle of the date and time. This makes SQL server think the date is in [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
SET DATEFORMAT myd
SELECT DATEPART(month,cast('2017-12-11T14:30:41.007' as datetime))

SET DATEFORMAT dym
SELECT DATEPART(month,cast('2017-12-11T14:30:41.007' as datetime))

/*

Output:
12
12

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

`'2017-12-14 14:30:41.007'` seems to follow ODBC canonical with milliseconds default standard for time, date, datetime2, and datetimeoffset. If you are using MS SQL you can use [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles) to cope with the specific style of the string parameter:

```
SELECT convert(datetime,'2017-12-14 14:30:41.007' , 121 )
```